# Saving file uploaded via ajax to Django model ImageField

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, django-models

The file is available as raw data in the request. How am I supposed to transform it to be saved on the disk represented by the `ImageField` inside a `model`.

Tried stuff:

```
file_ = File(request)
modelinstance.picture.save(filename, file_, save=False)
modelinstance.save()
```

and some variants of the above. An example on how to do this inside the django view would help.

Thanks!

Comment: Totally helped by this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232089/save-raw-post-data-to-filefield-using-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it like this

```
filename = request.GET[ 'yourfilename' ]

from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
file_contents = SimpleUploadedFile("%s" %(filename), request.raw_post_data)

modelinstance.picture.save(filename, file_contents, True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you used a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform), you wouldn't have anything special to do. ModelForm handles FileField/ImageField automatically.

If you really want to do it manually, django [has docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs#handling-uploaded-files)

Comment: That's only part of the question. The actual question is that my file is not in request.FILES since it is a ajax XHR request. So how do I read it from there and assign to my ImageField

Comment: You mean you have the file base64-encoded or something similar, inside the XHR request? That's interesting.
Check what the file-field wants. A file object? Does it need to be already saved on disk?

Comment: It is very complex to upload a file via ajax, this plugin makes it easy http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/ Also you should improve your question, how is it that "your file is not in request.FILES" in a comment and not in the question ? humhum ...